# Can jQuery change `$(window).width()`?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to change `$(window).width()` via jQuery, so that something like this is possible:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
   //menu 100px with $(window).width();
});
```

Comment: @JamWaffles, I have no idea about it, so ask if it could or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not.  The underlying DOM element itself doesn't support modifying the width of the browser window.  It is possible to change the dimensions of the content (outerWidth / innerWidth) area.  However I don't believe this has an affect on the size of the window which is what you seem to want to achieve

Comment: thanks. so how about scrollbar, is it inside the `width of the browser window`?

Answer (score 3):

You can control the size of a new browser window that you open with `window.open()`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.open for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about other browsers (tried it in Chrome and it didn't work), however FireFox will allow you to resize the window using:

```
window.resizeTo(1280,1024);
```

I have a bookmark with

```
javascript:window.resizeTo(1280,1024);
```

To resize the window to see what sites I develop look like at different resolutions.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears to be Firefox only.