# Modify $(window).width()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can jQuery change `$(window).width()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450941/can-jquery-change-window-width)

In jQuery, I can retrieve the value of the browser with $(window).width();
Can I modify it's value?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resize browser window with `window.resizeTo(x,y)` or `window.resizeBy(x,y)` . Nowadays, this only applies to windows that are opened programmatically.

Comment: I was using this $("#list").css('width', 320px); While it fit the screen nicely, I still can scroll the screen like this:

[link](https://forum.jquery.com/viewImage.do?fileId=14737000003028359&forumGroupId=14737000000003003)

[link](https://forum.jquery.com/viewImage.do?fileId=14737000003033417&forumGroupId=14737000000003003)